# C#: Radio Button doesn't have definition .IsChecked?

Tags: c#, winforms, radio-button, ischecked

I am writing a program to run a testing tool that has two cameras, named Pias and DinoLite.  The operator can select which camera is to be active by two radio buttons.  I am trying to implement an exception where if an operator tries to select a camera which is not connected, the program will ask if they want to restart with the correct camera installed.  If the operator says no, I would like the radio buttons to revert to the previous camera.  However, for some reason, the .IsChecked method for radio buttons is not available.  Is there a property I must change first?  I've seen other posts about using .IsChecked and I couldn't find a similar issue.

Here is my code for the radio button (forgive me if it's appalling, I'm a mechanical engineer by training):

```
    private void pias_mode_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please ensure the correct camera is installed.  Press OK when finished.", "Camera Switch", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
        if (pias_mode.Checked)
            Mode_Indicator.Text = "Pias Mode";
    }

    private void dino_mode_CheckedChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (dino_mode.Checked)
            Mode_Indicator.Text = "DINO Mode";
            measuringZ = 100;
            try //detects if DinoLite camera is connected
            {
                axDNVideoX1.Connected = true;
                axDNVideoX1.Preview = true;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                DialogResult dialogresult = MessageBox.Show("Could not find DinoLite camera.  Would you like to connect DinoLite camera?  This will require the program to exit.", "Device not Found", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
                if (dialogresult == DialogResult.Yes)
                {
                    Close();
                }
                else if (dialogresult == DialogResult.No)
                {
                    pias_mode.IsChecked = true;
                }
            }
    }
```

Visual studio tells me there is no definition for '.IsChecked'

Here is what it looks like:

[image: No definition for '.IsChecked']

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
YOU should __always__ TAG your questions correctly so one can see it on the questions page!

Comment: Hi, sorry I'm not familiar with this, as I'm quite new to Visual Studio.  I had it tagged as C#.  I would appreciate constructive help for future reference.

Comment: Well, go ahead and add the Winfroms tag to your question!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can not change the value of IsChecked. Instead use the `Checked` [property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.radiobutton.checked?view=netframework-4.8#System_Windows_Forms_RadioButton_Checked) of the RadioButton.

Comment: I thought this was correct, but could be more authoritative. I hope you don't mind the edit.